# Spock Mock not working for unit test

Tags: groovy, spock

I am getting weird results from a Spock unit test that I *thought* was being caused by a misuse of Groovy's [`TupleConstructor`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html) annotation. However, thanks to the help of another user, I see it is a problem with the way Spock is creating mocks. Although I have fixed the issue by replacing the injected mocks with real instances, I need to in fact get mocks working here.

My main classes:

```
@Canonical
@TupleConstructor(callSuper = true)
abstract class Vehicle {
    Long id
}

@Canonical
@TupleConstructor(callSuper = true, includeSuperProperties = true)
abstract class Foobaz extends Vehicle {
    String name
    String label
    String description
}

@Canonical
@TupleConstructor(callSuper = true, includeSuperProperties = true)
class Fizz extends Foobaz {
    // This is an empty class that creates a meaningful name over the
    // abstract Foobaz parent class. This may seem like bad design in
    // this analogy, but I assure you it makes sense (from a Domain-Driven
    // Design perspective) in my actual application.
}

@Canonical
@TupleConstructor(callSuper = true, includeSuperProperties = true)
class Car extends Vehicle {
    Fizz fizz1
    Fizz fizz2

    @Override
    String toString() {
        "${fizz1.name} - ${fizz2.name}"
    }
}
```

My Spock test:

```
class CarSpec extends Specification {
    def "toString() generates a correct string"() {
        given: "a Car with some mocked dependencies"
        String f1 = 'fizzy'
        String f2 = 'buzzy'
        Fizz fizz1 = Mock(Fizz)
        Fizz fizz2 = Mock(Fizz)

        fizz1.name >> f1
        fizz2.name >> f2

        Car car = new Car(1L, fizz1, fizz2)

        when: "we call toString()"
        String str = car.toString()

        then: "we get a correctly formatted string"
        "${f1} - ${f2}" == str
    }
}
```

But when I run this I get the following failure/error:

```
Condition not satisfied:

"${f1} - ${f2}" == str
  |        |     |  |
  fizzy    buzzy |  null - null
                 false
                 <omitting details here for brevity>

Expected :null - null

Actual   :fizzy - buzzy
```

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Comment: You didn't provide the Fizz class. I have tested your example with a simple Fizz interface, and it works

Comment: Thanks @JérémieB (+1) - I'll include `Fizz` if you *absolutely* think its necessary, but since they're being injected as Mocks, why do they matter?

Comment: It's probably how you are mocking fizz which is the cause of your bug. with a `Fizz { String getName() }`, your example works. So it's not related to `@TupleConstructor`

Comment: Not the answer, but you don't need `Fizz fizz1 = Mock(Fizz)`, just `Fizz fizz1 = Mock()` will do

Comment: why are you mocking a class, instead of creating a new instance ? however, with groovy 2.4.5, and cglib/objenesis, this example works too

Comment: I mock all dependencies in my unit tests, my opinion is that anything else (besides Java primitives, exceptions and very-well tested 3rd party classes) is not a true unit test.

Comment: A side note: I'm running this test from inside IntelliJ...could IntelliJ somehow be interfering with the AST transforms that `TupleConstructor` require?

Comment: Ahhh, @JérémieB - you're correct! Replacing the mocked `Fizz` instances with actual instances works! Any ideas why?! And if you can put that explanation in an answer I'll happily give you the green check!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From our discussion on a different one of @smeeb's [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37076536/1073826), I looked into this a bit more since I was very confused why this wasn't working.

I created my own test.

```
class SomeTest extends Specification {

    static class Driver {

        String getName(Superclass superclass) {
            return superclass.name
        }
    }

    static abstract class Superclass {
        String name
    }

    static class Subclass extends Superclass {
    }


    def 'test'() {
        given:
        def driver = new Driver()
        def subclass = Mock(Subclass)

        subclass.name >> 'test'

        expect:
        driver.getName(subclass) == 'test'
    }
}
```

It failed with the same problem that @smeeb saw.

```
driver.getName(subclass) == 'test'
|      |       |         |
|      null    |         false
|              Mock for type 'Subclass' named 'subclass'
```

I tried changing a few different things and found that when I either removed the `abstract` modifier from `Superclass` or changed the `return superclass.name` to `return superclass.getName()` the test began working.

It seems there is a weird interaction on the Groovy-level between getting inherited public fields from an abstract superclass using the auto-generated accessors.

So, in your case either remove `abstract` modifier from `FooBaz`, or change your code to:

```
@Override
String toString() {
    "${fizz1.getName()} - ${fizz2.getName()}"
}
```

Comment: So basically Groovy and Spock are getting too fancy for one another. I like Groovy and all, but g*d d*mn if I don't miss my type safety!

Comment: I feel the same way.  I can't find this particular case documented anywhere, but I've run into other Groovy gotchas over the past couple years that I spent hours on only to find an "won't fix" bug ticket on their tracker.  One in particular was involving calling a closure in an abstract super class's method from a subclass resulted in the closure not being able to access private fields and methods in the super class.  Java 8 lambdas don't have this issue.  I'm in the process of getting experience with Kotlin (if Scala and Groovy had a child) so I can recommend it for my next work assignment.

Answer (score 4):

If you change your specification to this:

```
class CarSpec extends Specification {
    def "toString() generates a correct string"() {
        given: "a Car with some mocked dependencies"
        String f1 = 'fizzy'
        String f2 = 'buzzy'
        Fizz fizz1 = Mock()
        Fizz fizz2 = Mock()

        Car car = new Car(1L, fizz1, fizz2)

        when: "we call toString()"
        String str = car.toString()

        then: "we get a correctly formatted string + getProperty('name') is called once on each Mock"
        "$f1 - $f2" == str

        1 * fizz1.getProperty('name') >> f1
        1 * fizz2.getProperty('name') >> f2
    }
}
```

So you define the interactions in the `then` block, then it should all work fine...

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates (+1) - I'll give it a try, but to me, that seems a bit backwards + counterintuitive! You're saying that you wire up your mocks...after already making assertions using them?!? In Java/Mockito land, you create your mocks, wire/configure them (to return/behave however you want), and *then* you use them. It sounds like in Spock-land, you create your mocks, use them, and then wire/configure them?!?

Comment: Yes. [Like in the documentation](https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_mocking)

Comment: Right. But that example just does *verification*, @tim_yates. What you are suggesting above is *verification + configuration*. I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm saying Spock is strange and counterintuitive. Also, that `getProperty()` method shows up nowhere in that link, so it's not just "in the documentation".

Comment: That's groovy. `obj.prop` calls `getProperty` first, so that is what gets called on your mock (as your mock doesn't implement getProperty, it doesn't get further than that)

Comment: If `obj.prop` becomes `getProperty` then I guess the real question here is: does `obj.prop` also become `name`, especially when I use double elvis `>>`.

Comment: Think I was confusing, I meant `obj.name` in groovy first hits `obj.getProperty('name')`

Comment: I faced the similar issue. In my case  (it's too long to describe it here) `1 * fizz1.getProperty('name') >> f1` doesn't work (I get `null` when code under test appeals to property `name`). But `1 * fizz1.getName() >> f1` works fine.