# Spock block mocks and where to wire them

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

I have seen Spock tests where mocks are wired up & configured in the `given` block (which is where it makes the most sense to me), as well as cases where the only way to get the test to pass required me to wire/configure the mocks inside the `then` block, which is just plain silly to me. An example of the latter is a question [that I asked some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656949/spock-mock-not-working-for-unit-test).

**So I ask: What determines *where* to actually wire/config a mock, either in `given` or in `then`?** I really hope the answer isn't just "*keep playing with it until it works*", because that's too non-deterministic for my tiny robot brain.

Comment: can you change the title of this question so it rhymes more?

Comment: that was intentional :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocks and Stubs should be instantiated in the `setup`/`given` block or even in `setup()` method if you are going to use them in multiple tests and want to reduce boilerplate.

In my opinion, Mocks and Stubs behavior should be defined in the most-narrowly scoped place that makes sense. `then` makes the most sense usually, but defining general behavior that you don't really care about checking closely could be put in the `setup`/`given` block or even in the `setup()` method.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Peterson (+1) - I (respectfully) disagree about `then` making the most sense, but that's a subjective argument I'm not interested in making right now! **However**, as the link provided above demonstrates, there are certainly use cases for when wiring/configuring mocks inside the `given` *simply does not work*. And my question is **what drives this?** Meaning, in what scenarios will wiring/configging mocks in `given` work, and when must that be done in `then`? Thanks again!

Comment: In the other question, I believe that if you had used the `fizz1.getProperty('name')` instead of `fizz1.name` in the `given` block, it would have worked as well.

Comment: The root of your confusion regarding the 'counter-intuitive' nature of Spock is probably due to your experience with other Java mocking frameworks.  Spock is doing something under the hood to call the expectations in the `then` block before the `when` block. Attach a debugger and you'll see the order in which things are called. When I use non-Spock mocking (such as Camel MockEndpoints), I typically use `expect` blocks instead of `when`/`then` so I can manually order the expectations how I want them.

Comment: Thanks again @Jon Peterson (+1 for both) - now I think we're getting somewhere. So, in my other question, could I have also used `fizz1.getName() >> f1` to make it work in the `given` block, or would I still need to use `fizz1.getProperty('name')` as you already suggested? If `fizz1.getName()` would *not* have worked, then **why?** I think answering *that* will help me understand all of this. Thanks again!

Comment: The `Fizz` class you defined in your question did not have a `getName()` method or a `name` field (public fields will autogenerate accessor methods in Groovy).  Because of this, calling `fizz.name` was not calling a manually defined `getName()` or an autogenerated one, but instead was calling `getProperty('name')` (see GroovyObject docs).  If you tried to call `getName()` there would be a MethodNotFound exception thrown.  I would not recommended to using the `getProperty()` style because of issues like this, and instead specifically define public fields that will generate accessors.

Comment: Thanks again @Jon Peterson, but `Fizz` extended `Foobaz` which *did* have a public field called `name`....is inheritance somehow mucking this up? Either way `fizz1.name` and `fizz1.getName()` are valid method invocations that do in fact return the `Foobaz#name` field....thoughts?

Comment: Appologies, I did not see that. This was very curious to me, so I did some messing around.  I posted an answer on that question with code snippets.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37080899/1073826

Comment: Thank @Jon I really appreciate you looking into this and verifying that I'm not losing my mind!